# execute command denied to user readonlyuser

Tags: php, mysql

Although localhost has execute permission, I'm getting error below when I run query in my web application. What I did normally solves problem of other users in this and other forums but for some reason doesn't solve mine unless I'm missing something.

Note: When I run same query in navicat or anywhere else, it works fine.

Is there anything else to solve this problem?

Thanks

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT
get_balance('$deadline', '$id') AS Balance,
allow_submission('$id', '$term') AS Over
FROM dual
```

**ERROR:**

```
execute command denied to user 'readonlyuser'@'localhost' for routine 'mydb.allow_submission'
```

**WHAT I DID:** *In Navicat GUI and Linux terminal as `root` and `superuser`.*

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE mydb.allow_submission TO 'readonlyuser'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are passing parameters to `allow_submission`, I think, that it's a function, not a procedure.

Try this:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION mydb.allow_submission TO 'readonlyuser'@'localhost';
```

Comment: I always say, if you have been working on something, take a break otherwise 2+2 becomes 5! I don't know what made me write PROCEDURE there. Thank you very much.